# Setting up Bind9 Nameserver. Editing /etc/init.d/sysklogd help?

Tags: debian, bind, nameservers

I'm following along with [this tutorial](http://linux.justinhartman.com/DNS_Installation_and_Setup_using_BIND9) and I've successfully gotten as far as a part which tells me to edit the "sysklogd" file in /etc/init.d/

The tutorial tells me that in order to allow logging of bind activity, I need to replace the line

`SYSLOGD=""`

with

```
SYSLOGD="-a /var/lib/named/dev/log"
```

The trouble is that I can't find the first line.

Has the sysklogd file changed since the time this tutorial was written? Should I just inset the line myself?

Here is the contents of sysklogd below. I'm sorry it looks horrendous, I tried to format it better but it's doesn't seem to be happening for me. Just hoping it might jog someones memory.

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/sysklogd: start the system log daemon.

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:             sysklogd
# Required-Start:       $remote_fs $time
# Required-Stop:        $remote_fs $time
# Should-Start:         $network
# Should-Stop:          $network
# Default-Start:        2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:         0 1 6
# Short-Description:    System logger
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin

pidfile=/var/run/syslogd.pid
binpath=/sbin/syslogd

test -x $binpath || exit 0

test ! -r /etc/default/syslogd || . /etc/default/syslogd

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

create_xconsole()
{
    # Only proceed if /dev/xconsole is used at all
    if ! grep -q '^[^#].*/dev/xconsole' /etc/syslog.conf
    then
        return
    fi

    if [ ! -e /dev/xconsole ]; then
        mknod -m 640 /dev/xconsole p
    else
        chmod 0640 /dev/xconsole
    fi
    chown root:adm /dev/xconsole
    test ! -x /sbin/restorecon || /sbin/restorecon /dev/xconsole
}
running()
{
    # No pidfile, probably no daemon present
    #
    if [ ! -f $pidfile ]
    then
        return 1
    fi

    pid=`cat $pidfile`

    # No pid, probably no daemon present
    #
    if [ -z "$pid" ]
    then
        return 1
    fi

    if [ ! -d /proc/$pid ]
    then
        return 1
    fi

    cmd=`cat /proc/$pid/cmdline | tr "\000" "\n"|head -n 1`

    # No syslogd?
    #
    if [ "$cmd" != "$binpath" ]
    then
        return 1
    fi

    return 0
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    log_begin_msg "Starting system log daemon..."
    create_xconsole
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $pidfile --name syslogd --startas $binpath -- $SYSLOGD
    log_end_msg $?
    test -d /lib/init/rw/sendsigs.omit.d || mkdir -p /lib/init/rw/sendsigs.omit.d
    test ! -f /lib/init/rw/sendsigs.omit.d/sysklogd || rm -f /lib/init/rw/sendsigs.omit.d/sysklogd
    ln -s $pidfile /lib/init/rw/sendsigs.omit.d/sysklogd
    ;;
 stop)
    log_begin_msg "Stopping system log daemon..."
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile $pidfile --name syslogd
    log_end_msg $?
    ;;
  reload|force-reload)
    log_begin_msg "Reloading system log daemon..."
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --signal 1 --pidfile $pidfile --name syslogd
    log_end_msg $?
    ;;
  restart)
    log_begin_msg "Restarting system log daemon..."
    start-stop-daemon --stop --retry 5 --quiet --pidfile $pidfile --name syslogd
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $pidfile --name syslogd --startas $binpath -- $SYSLOGD
    log_end_msg $?
    ;;
  reload-or-restart)
    if running
    then
        $0 reload
    else
        $0 start
    fi
    ;;
  *)
    log_success_msg "Usage: /etc/init.d/sysklogd {start|stop|reload|restart|force-reload|reload-or-restart}"
    exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in `/etc/default/syslogd`.